# Continuously scrolling UI Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d-games

So I am working working on something in unity (2d game). I have a list of button (UI) on my scene and I want to implement a scrolling mechanism. What is the best way to go about it? Currently , I can scroll through horizontally because I have added a "scroll rect" to the the canvas holding the buttons as I start the game. However when I try to scroll back (horizontally, it goes beyond the Buttons. Is there a way to make the scrolling continuous such that as I scroll, from the first UI element when I get to the last one and I keep scrolling, it continues with the first element. or what should I do. please let me Know If i should clarify.

Comment: I think you would have to implement this yourself. There is nothing built-in I'm aware of that behaves like what you want to achieve

Comment: If you google the description of your problem, you will find the Unity UI-extension repository.

Comment: @fafase you're speaking of this, correct? https://bitbucket.org/UnityUIExtensions/unity-ui-extensions/src/release/Runtime/Scripts/Utilities/UI_InfiniteScroll.cs

Comment: that one and actually there are others. Not sure what is the state of UIExtension, it used to be free but I have seen mentioned of Asset Store lately. The dev is quite helping and available.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Scroll rect](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-ScrollRect.html) you can set the movement type. I don't think the kind of "infinite scroll" you are asking for is available.
For your case, I think that the Use Elastic or Clamped mode to force the content to remain within the bounds of the Scroll Rect should do the work.

In the case of the infinite scroll specifically needed, you would need to ask for that explicitely and show your attempt for more specific help.